# The sort function is changing a variable that i am not sorting

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i am having a issue with the sort function as you see i have made a array called newSiteArr and i make a variable called orderd equal to it i then sort the orderd variable but then i make a new variable xyorderd = to orderd and the sort it in reverse then when i console.log the newSiteArr[0] it gives me the value of 8 instead of its original value of 0 which seems strange seeing as i have not done any sorting on newSiteArr and also the orderd[0] variable returns 8 when i sorted it in order from lowest to highest.

Please could anyone help me to understand what is going on and why this is happening it seems like a bug to me because why would the newSiteArr be changed when i haven't done anything to it???

```js
const newSiteArr = [0, 4, 2, 5, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1];

var orderd = newSiteArr;

console.log(newSiteArr[0]);


orderd.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
});


console.log(newSiteArr[0]);

var xyorderd = orderd.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a < b) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
});
//  logs the value 8 when i am not sorting it
console.log(newSiteArr[0]);

console.log(xyorderd[0]);

//  logs the value 8 when i havent sorted it in reverse
console.log(orderd[0]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.sort` sorts the array in place - it does not return a new array. Also just assigning it does not make a copy of the array.

Comment: thank you for the answer .So it is sorting the original array when i have not asked for that? your telling me that if i copy a variable to another variable i do not have 2 different variable ? sounds strange im having a hard time grasping that.

Comment: `var newArr = oldArr` does not copy the array - just the reference *to* the array

Comment: sorry i have just learnt that the new variable is a pointer to the original.

Comment: @jordantechy exactly. thats what "reference" means

Comment: Wow i just looked through heaps of my code and i have made lots of problems because i did not know that . thank you